# apache httpclient: AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch

Tags: java, ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

Seldomly, I'm getting this exception:

> javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!

That's my http client configuration:

```java
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContextBuilder.create()
    .loadTrustMaterial(
        new URL(visorApiProperties.getTrustStore()),
        visorApiProperties.getTrustStorePassword().toCharArray()
    )
    .build();

SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> socketFactoryRegistry = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create()
    .register("https", sslsf)
    .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
    .build();

PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager cm = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(socketFactoryRegistry);

httpClientBuilder.setConnectionManager(cm);
```

I don't quite figure out what does it mean.

I've took a look on other stackoverflow questions, but I don't quite figure out what would I do in order to solve this problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For me problem was in sertificate.
If you try execute this curl result will be the same.

> curl -I -vv --cert sertificate_location --cert-type p12 --pass password url

OpenSSL SSL_read: error:0A000119:SSL routines::decryption failed or bad record mac, errno 0

Answer (score 0):

The exception javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException means that the data could not be encoded and decoded using authenticated encryption with additional data (AEAD). "Tag mismatch!" indicates that the tag value (the value added to the encrypted data to allow for data integrity verification after decryption) is inconsistent between the sending and receiving sides.

To solve this problem, the following should be verified:

- Is the encryption key the same on both sides?
- Are there any issues with the trust certificates in the configured trust store?
- Is the version of the javax.crypto library compatible on both sides?
- Are the sending side and receiving side using the same encryption mode and encryption settings?